# Can Ted die a natural death?

Tags: movie, immortality, ted

In the 2012 release movie, [*Ted*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ted_%28film%29), can Ted the teddybear die a natural death? In what aspects is the life within him different from the life within humans?

Comment: He does appear to get older (in mindset as well as physically - his fur is less plush etc) - (speculative answer) His lifespan *could* be the same as John's as it was John's wish for a friend that brought him alive in the first place - making them linked together.

Answer (score 6):

At the end of the film, Ted is killed by Donny and then reborn as a result of Lori's "wish upon a star"

> **TED:** *Even more than me. She’s your thunder buddy now. She’s--*
>
> **Ted closes his eyes... and dies.** ANGLE DIRECTLY ABOVE TED as we pull away, and it starts to rain...

According to the [original script](http://www.pages.drexel.edu/%7Eina22/splaylib/Screenplay-Ted.pdf);

> "Lori’s eyes widen a bit in recognition. She stares at the shooting
> star for a beat, then closes her eyes and makes a wish..."

[image]

Obviously he can "die" as a result of violence or accident although the mechanism is somewhat vague given that his "life" is a result of completely unfathomable magic in the first place.